# Attribute for CallContext .LogicalGetData / .LogicalSetData?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, async-await, dry

Is there an attribute for CallContext .LogicalGetData / .LogicalSetData that would allow using it in similar way as `[ThreadStaticAttribute]`?

Or do I have to each time create property with explicit getter/setter and the most DRY way is to create an wrapper bellow?

```
static readonly LC<MyObj> myField = new MyObj();
```